# Splitting a string/list using a specific character as an axis

Tags: python, string, list, split

Apologies if this is a duplicate, I did a thorough search and couldn't find an answer to this particular issue.

I am building a program that will take input in the format "XdY" (that is, 4d6, 1d20, 3d10 etc.) and generate the desired dice roll. I need to turn the input string into two separate values for the number of dice rolled and number of sides on said dice. For example, given

```
roll = "3d6"
```

I want to end up with

```
number = int("3")
sides = int("6")
```

I'm envisioning a solution that will split the original string into one string containing everything to the left of the "d" and one with everything to the right of it, while discarding the "d" character itself. As of now, I have the program set up to handle "number" and "sides" values, but only if they are input as two separate ints.

Comment: Did you look at the methods available for a string?  One of the names should jump out at you.

Comment: Mate, you should Google. Use `roll.split('d')`. For more on the subject, check here - https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.split  
This is not a question that should appear on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple solution:

```
number, sides = map(int, roll.split('d'))
```

Just split your `roll` string by `'d'`, convert obtained strings to numbers and assign them to `number` and `sides` respectively.

Answer (score 1):

OR:

```
>>> roll = "3d6"
>>> number,sides=(int(i) for i in roll.split('d'))
>>> number
3
>>> sides
6
```

Comment: I was actually about to write the same thing but tuple comprehension. If you don't need the list's mutability then it is best to use a tuple instead as it has better performance assignment wise. `number, sides = (int(i) for i in roll.split('d'))`. Also, by far the easiest and fastest answer.

Comment: Learn something new every day. Thank you for the correction.

Comment: @BoobyTrap Yw. Have a nice day, :), 

Answer (score 0):

A simple regex will work well:

```
match = re.match(r"(\d+)d(\d+)", "2d10")
m.group(1) # '2'
m.group(2) # '10'
```